# Laravel creates a new session on every reload

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, session

Every time I refresh the browser a new file is created in the `/sotrage/framework/sessions`
the problem doesn't happen in my localhost but it happens on the public host ( Bluehost )

```
var_dump(session()->all());
```

results:

```
array(1) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "xNETyNoJaC0i9Fm9gIPX49rQQ4Kzz4Oac3iPz8K6" }
```

(with different `_token` on every page reload)

**Edit**

here's my config.session file (without comments)

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => null,
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    'http_only' => true,
];
```

I've spent hours trying to solve this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the permissions on the directory are correct on bluehost.

Comment: the permissions on '/storage/framework/session' were 755 ( is that wrong? ) I changed them to 777 but it's still the same

Comment: Do you see any files in that directory?

Comment: Yes, A new file is created in that directory every time I reload the browser

Comment: the `'/'` path may be different for bluehost?